# Generate a list of years with the same month and day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'd like to generate a list of `'%Y-%m-%d'` of the same month and day in different years.

I tried

```
import pandas as pd
pd.date_range('2014-04-01', '2018-04-01', freq='BYS').strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
```

It returns `['2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2018-01-01']`

Expected result `['2014-04-01, '2015-04-01, '2016-04-01', '2017-04-01', '2018-04-01']`

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to generate datetime between `2014-04-01` and `2018-04-01` by year, `04-01` is the start day of month. You can use a frequency `12MS` where `12M` is 12 months and `S` is month start.

```py
pd.date_range('2014-04-01', '2018-04-01', freq='12MS').strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()

['2014-04-01', '2015-04-01', '2016-04-01', '2017-04-01', '2018-04-01']
```

If you want to generate datetime between `2014-04-02` and `2018-04-02` by year, you can add an offset to generated date between `2014-04-02` and `2018-04-02`.

```py
(pd.date_range('2014-04-01', '2018-04-01', freq='12MS') + pd.DateOffset(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()

['2014-04-02', '2015-04-02', '2016-04-02', '2017-04-02', '2018-04-02']
```

Reason why `pd.date_range('2014-04-02', '2018-04-02', freq='12MS')` won't work is that `12MS` generates month start between `2014-04-02` and `2018-04-02` that is `2014-05-01` to `2017-05-01`.

Comment: Looks like this a better answer then what I wrote below... This should be the accepted answer, I'm deleting mine.